# How to Pass a Func<string, string> to a function that takes a Func<object, object>

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, func

Ok so I've got this simple class

```
    private class TFTheOne
    {
        private object value;

        public TFTheOne(object value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public TFTheOne Bind(Func<object, object> func)
        {
            value = func(value);
            return this;
        }

        public void PrintMe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
```

And this function

```
    public static string ReadFile(string filePath)
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    }
```

Now when I try to pass `ReadFile` to the `TFTheOne.Bind` function

```
 new TFTheOne(args[0]).Bind(ReadFile);
```

I get this error message

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to
> 'Func<object, object>'

Even when I try to cast `ReadFile`

```
new TFTheOne(args[0]).Bind((Func<object, object>)ReadFile);
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why does the method take `Func<object, object>`? How would your `string` input map onto the `object` input, and your `object` output map onto your `string` output? It seems like somewhere where you're likely to introduce bugs.

Comment: What should happen if Bind ends up calling this func with something that isn't a string?

Comment: A simple bridge would be something like `.Bind(o => ReadFile(o as string))`, but you really need to answer (to yourself) the question I posed in my first comment.

Comment: Your class might be simple, but its convoluted and your intention is unclear. This seems like some sort of Fluent Api. However what is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @TheGeneral Coding assignment as an introduction to Monads. C# definitely wouldn't have been my first choice, however I am sort of stuck with it at the moment.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for the help, and thanks for pointing out the flaws. This is for a coding assignment though. Just sort of following instructions.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but regarding monads in C#, Eric Lippert has written a very interesting [series of articles](https://ericlippert.com/2013/02/21/monads-part-one) about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Func<T, TResult>` is *contravariant* with respect to `T`, so only less specific types can be used as input.

In your case, you would need to wrap your `ReadFile` method to ensure it works with any `object`.

Something like this would work, depending on your requirements:

```
new TFTheOne(args[0]).Bind(o => ReadFile(o?.ToString()));
```

Although a "better" design would be to overload `Bind`:

```
public TFTheOne Bind(Func<string, object> func)
{
    value = func(value);
    return this;
}
```

Now because `TResult` is *covariant*, this should compile fine:

```
new TFTheOne(args[0]).Bind(ReadFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Consider this case: your class TFTheOne holds an integer value, if you would be allowed to do that then your function would crash when you call it as it expects an string.

What you can do is to create a lambda that surrounds your `Func<string, string>()` and checks if the parameter passed to it is really a string:

```
.Bind((o) => o is string ? ReadFile((string)o) : null);
```

Comment: Looking at the code, particularly `Console.WriteLine(value)`, it seems that calling `ToString()` on the object is more appropriate than using `null`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay It depends, if `o` is a class instance `ToString` would not be useful at all.

Comment: There is already a method that is calling `ToString()` on `value` (by using `Console.WriteLine(object)`). Using your implementation, you now have different behaviour when you pass a `string` to the constructor or via `Bind`, which surely isn't desirable.